# Django models.CheckConstraint causing "TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable"

Tags: python, django

I have a model named **`Therapist`** written as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Therapist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also a model named **`Appointment`** with some constraints.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    therapist = models.ForeignKey(Therapist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slot = models.DateTimeField()


    def validate_not_match_therapist_client(self):
        if self.therapist.user == self.client:
            raise ValidationError('Therapist and client cannot be the same user.')
    
    
    def clean(self):
        self.validate_not_match_therapist_client()
    
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
         
            # Same client booking multiple appointments at the same slot (different therapists) 
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['client', 'slot'],
                name='multiple_same_date_time_appointment' 
            ),
            
            # therapist booking his/her own appointment
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=~models.Q(therapist__user=models.F('client')),
                name='therapist_client_are_same' 
            )

        ]
```

In this project, **`Therapist`** objects can also book appointments but I wanted to restrict them from booking any appointments with itself. So, I wrote the second constraint like this:

```
# therapist booking his/her own appointment
models.CheckConstraint(
    check=~models.Q(therapist__user=models.F('client')),
    name='therapist_client_are_same' 
)
```

It works fine when I run **`makemigrations`**, but when I run **`migrate`** it throws this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/project//manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1560,in check
    *cls._check_constraints(databases),
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2303,in _check_constraints
    % connection.display_name,
  File "/home/user/project/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57,in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

If I remove the **`models.CheckConstraint`**, it works fine. Did I write that constraint wrong?

I tried to restrict the **`Appointment`** model to save an instance if the **`therapist`** and **`client`** attributes are the same user. That means, if **`therapist.user`** (a **`User`** object) and **`client`** (also a **`User`** object) are the same. So, I made a negated query like this:

**`~models.Q(therapist__user=models.F('client'))`** , expecting it would restrict the db from saving an appointment where the therapist is also the client.

Comment: You can not check constraints that span over multiple tables.